# nexus 4 connecting app-inventor by usb

Tags: android, macos, usb, app-inventor

I tried connecting my nexus4 to app-inventor using wifi and it worked fine,
now when i try using usb (after enabling usb debugging) it gives me this error
`Detailed error: Unable to get SyncService for device`, i searched the error and all i could find is people aren't installing the drivers on their windows pc

but i'm using mac mountain lion, and it works fine with all of my other android phones including wildfire, desire C, galaxy Ace, S2 and S3, but not with this nexus4

what am i missing? anyone had this problem and managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching online, and messing around with the adb,
i found blog post that for phones running android 4.2, they have to update the Android SDK, on their machines to get it back working, and since only the nexus 4 from all of the other devices i working on runs 4.2 (jelly bean)

to update Android SDK, go the SDK folder and open `android` usually found in `Documents/Android SDK/tools/android` you'll see the list of installed software, and there will be notifications beside what ever needs an update

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully connect to App Inventor on the Nexus when I ran "adb devices" from the Mac command line which killed and restarted the android device handler.  The error I had received from the Blocks Editor was "unable to start sync services".  I'm using it now and it's working, no need to update my SDK.  I theorize that restarting the device handler when you updated the SDK was what actually fixed the issue, not the SDK update's content.  Just my theory, and I'm still new at this.